# An error ocurred while starting the kernel - spyder

Tags: python, spyder

An error ocurred while starting the kernel

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in *run_module_as_main
"**main**", mod_spec)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in *run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console_*main**.py", line 11, in
start.main()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 287, in main
import_spydercustomize()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\console\start.py", line 39, in import_spydercustomize
import spydercustomize
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 27, in
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython_*init**.py", line 54, in
from .core.application import Application
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\IPython\core\application.py", line 23, in
from traitlets.config.application import Application, catch_config_error
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config_*init*_.py", line 6, in
from .application import *
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\application.py", line 19, in
from traitlets.config.configurable import Configurable, SingletonConfigurable
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\configurable.py", line 12, in
from .loader import Config, LazyConfigValue, _is_section_key
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\traitlets\config\loader.py", line 16, in
from ipython_genutils.path import filefind
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site‑packages\ipython_genutils\path.py", line 13, in
import random
File "C:\Users\VelammalM29\random.py", line 5, in
l1=eval(input("enter a list:"))
EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Comment: Googled and tried all the possible ways...kindly help me in this regard

Comment: looks like there is an error in your "C:\Users\VelammalM29\random.py" file. Could this file have been open in the IDE the last time you saved it? It may also be a name conflict. I would rename the file and try to open spyder again.